# angular directive does not render

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-directive

I'm having problems with angular directives. I created a custom directive but it's not appearing and i don't know why. I can access the view specified in templateUrl with using localhost.

If somebody could help me that would just be great.

Thanks.

messageListDirective.js

```
angular.module('neat')
    .directive('message-list', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            templateUrl: '/views/utils/messageList.html'
        }
    });
```

messageList.html

```
<h4>MESSAGE LIST</h4>
```

And the view where I'm using the directive:

messageBoard.html

```
<message-list></message-list>
```

Comment: are you getting any error in console ?

Comment: No, no errors in console

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change directive:

```
.directive('message-list', function() {
```

to

```
.directive('messageList', function() {
```

angular normalize element tags. Read this for  more [info](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#creating-custom-directives_matching-directives)

Answer (score 1):

Did you import ng-controller="neat" in your messageBoard.html ?
 
If yes I think you should check the url to template.

Comment: Yes, I have a controller associated with the messageBoard.html. I was just creating the directive to organize some code, the other code in messageBoard.html worked fine.